# Python, storing a list and inserting into one column of table

Tags: python, mysql

The file I am reading in is formatted as follows:

```
12       #block belonging to ID1
78
60
98
7

65      #block belonging to ID2
14
22
```

Each block is terminated by a blank line and each block belongs to one ID. I want to insert this info into a table with two fields ID_from (which is the ID of the block is belongs to) and ID_to(the numbers within the block). So for ex:

```
ID_from    ID_to
1          12
1          78
1          60
1          98
1          7
2          65
2          14
2          22
```

I have a composite primary key which is the combination of these two fields which allows me to repeat the same ID in the ID_from column. This is my code relevant to the question:

```
citations = line
my_list = []
        my_list.append(citations)
        my_list = " ".join(my_list)

db1.execute('''INSERT INTO citations(
                        ID_from, ID_to) VALUES(%s,%s)''',
                        (ID, my_list))

conn.commit()
```

(ID has be defined earlier in the code). What I believe to have achieved with this code is created a list- citations_collect[] and appended each line of a block to the list- essentially a list of all values that should be inserted into the ID_to column. The current output I am getting is just the last value in each block and its corresponding block ID it appears in. ie:

```
ID_from    ID_to
1           7
2           22
```

My guess is that I should be putting my execute query into a loop but I am not certain of what the loop should consist of. What I was trying to do with the join function was to store the values of each block in a list on one line separated by a space and that would have been simpler to insert into a table but I hasnt made a difference to my output. 
I am new to python and mysql so I appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to recommend something without seeing your complete code. Anyway, I guess that it is because your are reading the file line by line in a loop and in every loop your are defining `my_list`. So, in every loop `my_list` contains only one item, and at the end of the block your writing this one last item to your database. 
You can try something like this:

```
id_from = 1
my_list = []
for line in file:
    if line.strip() == '':
        # update your database
        id_from += 1
        my_list = []
    else:
        my_list.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
list1 = f.read().splitlines()

id_from = 1
for id_to in list1:
    if id_to == '':
        id_from += 1
        continue
    db1.execute('''INSERT INTO citations(
                    ID_from, ID_to) VALUES(%s,%s)''',
                    (id_from, id_to)) 
conn.commit()
```

You can perhaps use your sql queries in more efficient way rather than this.